# Unwanted collisions from colliders - disabled in matrix and layers are checked

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a player object that I put on the "Player" layer. I unticked Player/Player in the collision matrix(not the physics2D one).

[image: layer masks]

That made it so I could walk through another player without colliding.
But I noticed that if I jump ontop of another player then I get stuck on the "head". https://gyazo.com/112d91b4edc3bb5e1de827ff69b9297d

I tried debugging from an OnCollisionEnter function but it shows nothing while I am ontop of the other player and It printed when I was on the ground.

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    print(collision.gameObject);
    print(collision.gameObject.layer);
    print(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>());
}
```

Disabling the collider on one of the players at runtime obviously made me fall through the other player but I can't have it like that.

Comment: How are you handling the character physics, especially how do you detect touching the ground? I'm guessing that there is a raycast that isn't properly ignoring the `Player` layer.

Comment: Thanks alot, it was the raycast layermask! I knew the change I made was gonna come back and bite me. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raycast used to detect the ground for the purposes of handling character physics does not have the correct `layerMask`.

It needs to include the player `layerMask` so that it does not result in a false positive for contact with the ground.